# NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle : not getting values for key

Tags: ios, iphone, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I am not able to get `values` for `keys` from the `InfoPlist`.

```
label.text = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"keyone", 
                                                nil, 
                                                AppDelegateObj.langBundle, nil));
```

In the `InfoPlist.strings` there is a value

```
"keyone" = "value one";
```

When I am running my app it is showing `UILabel` value as **keyone**

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
label.text = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"keyone", 
                 @"InfoPlist", 
                 AppDelegateObj.langBundle, nil));
```

Comment: never forget the name of the table is equal to the name of the localization file :P